# rounded corner menu item in css without CSS3!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I try to achieve the following output:

[image: normal view]

[image: after hover this will show]

i want to achieve this with HTML and CSS. I do not want to use CSS3(as my client do not want me to!). I try the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">registration</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sch's direc</a></li>
        <li><a href="">faculty &amp; staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Campuses</a></li>
        <li><a href="">History</a></li>            
        <li><a href="" >Mission</a><img src="images/right_menu.png" /></li>
        <li style="margin:0;padding:0;"><img src="images/left_menu.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul{
    list-style:none;

}

.menu li{
    float:right;
    background:url('images/menuBGrepX.png') repeat-x ;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.menu a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px 2px;
    float:left;
}



.menu li.selected{
    background:#A07E4E;

}

.menu li:hover{
    background:#A07E4E;
    color:#313131;

}
```

As you can expect the background color of `li` is changing when some one hover over it but the left and right image which I use for give a rounded border feel, it remain same. Please help me. You can check temporary work here : http://www.examplecode.info/enam/pleasehelp/.Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing you can do is have four nested elements, each with an image background for one corner. What is the reason for no CSS3 anyway? For non-supporting browsers you can use a JavaScript library like CSS3PIE.

Comment: A very important thing to consider is graceful degradation; use CSS3 for the rounded corners (which are not absolutely necessary) so browsers who support it (the latest stable versions of everything except IE do) will show it, and those who don't, won't.

Comment: @Neddy: +1 for CSS3Pie. @enam: I don't know why your client would specify not to use CSS3; it's a very short-sighted position. CSS3Pie will allow you to use CSS3 while still supporting older browsers.

Comment: @Neddy I will try CSS3Pie for my future project but for now Hussein solution perfectly work for me.

Comment: @Neddy I will try CSS3Pie for my future project but for now Hussein solution perfectly work for me. @Spudley I guess he do not know that :P , I just love CSS3! Thank you all for your replies . You guy's are really good. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery round corner plugin for cross browser round corners.

### http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

It's supported in all browsers including IE. It draws corners in IE using nested divs (no images). It also has native border-radius rounding in browsers that support it (Opera 10.5+, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome). So in those browsers the plugin simply sets a css property instead.

### Here's How to use it

You need to include the jQuery and the Corner js script before `</body>`. Then write your jQuery like $('div, p').corner('10px'); and place before ''. So your html will look like the below code. Here i'm making round corners for all `div` and `p` tags. If you want to do it for specific id or class then you can do something like `$('#myid').corner();`

```
<body>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <p class="y"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/malsup/corner/raw/master/jquery.corner.js?v2.11"></script>
<script>$('div, p').corner();</script>
</body>
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/VLPpk/1

Comment: for those who wants to achieve the output like my one has to write : $('.menu li').corner('top 3px');

Comment: @enam CSS3Pie would still be a better solution, because then only the non-compliment IE would have to load the JavaScript library. Using this, all browsers load the JavaScript and the standards compliment browsers are given the CSS3 version anyway.

Comment: CSS3Pie is heavier then the solution i provided.  You can easily issue an IE conditional statement so the corner script only loads in IE. `<!--[if IE]> <script>..</script> <![endif]-->`

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to know why your client asked you not to use CSS3 rounded corners? It sounds like a very short-sighted request. The only possible reason for specifying that is because certain browsers (IE6/7/8) do not support it.

In all other browsers, CSS `border-radius` is **by far** the best solution for rounded corners. All other solutions have major issues. There's a reason why the CSS3 solution is suddenly very popular, and it's because it solves all the problems that people were struggling with previously.

There are a number of solutions which allow CSS3 `border-radius` to be used by browsers which support it, and fall-back to Javascript for IE6/7/8. I would seriously recommend one of these solutions. The best one that I know of is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/), but there are a number of others.

Answer (score 0):

Is JavaScript allowed?
give all the elements an id, and add to the link an onMouseOver() and onMouseOut() event, where you call getElementById() on each of your borders and change them with a src="images/newimage.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

In your css for hovered list element you must change the image too. For example :

```
.menu li:hover {
   background:url('images/menuBGrepX_hover.png') repeat-x ;
   color:#313131;
}
```

You can't change the color of the image only with CSS, you must change the image entirely.